# When did they stop showing the Error Code 18486 on SQL Server 2016+ for locked out users

Tags: sql-server, errors

I have noticed that in SQL Server 2016 and later versions, I cannot seem to get the error code 18486 to show up for locked logins i.e.

> Login failed for user '%.*ls' because the account is currently locked out. The system administrator can unlock it. %.*ls

Documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors-18000-to-18999?view=sql-server-2016

Does anyone know when this changed to just appear as the generic login failed error code 18456?

SQL Server 2012:
[image]

SQL Server 2016:
[image]

Comment: Are you saying error 18486 is not in the SQL error log when an attempt is made to use the locked account? Details of login errors are not returned to the client, with the general login failure error returned instead.

Comment: Yes, but it used to do it in SQL Server 2012. The issue is that I could not find any official documentation of when it was changed.

Answer (score 1):

The error code was not removed, it exists in [all supported versions](https://sqlerrorcodes.com/error/18486). The link you've provided shows the error code still exists.

The value of a failed login given back to the user is always 18456 state 1. To get the actual reason you'll need to check the SQL Server errorlog or setup auditing. Anything else would be considered information disclosure and considered a security issue.

Comment: Yes, but it no longer is being displayed as the error code to the user. Instead, it gives 18456 as the error code whereas in SQL Server 2012, it displays as 18486.

Comment: I updated the question title as it was misleading.